# How to skip nested tags in iTextSharp with HtmlWorker

Tags: itext

I'm using HtmlWorker (I know I shouldn't) and I can ommit an Html tag's contained Text with let's say `class="ignoreme"`, using custom TagProcessor, by something like this:

```
public void StartElement(iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker worker, string tag, IDictionary<string, string> attrs)
{
    if(attrs.ContainsKey("class"))
    {                
        string[] src = attrs["class"].Split(' ');

        if (src.Length > 0 && src.Contains("ignoreme"))
        {
            worker.SetSkipText(true);
        }
        else
        {
            worker.CarriageReturn();
            worker.UpdateChain(tag, attrs);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        worker.CarriageReturn();
        worker.UpdateChain(tag, attrs);
    }

}
```

I also want to skip all contained child Html elements inside that element, but iTextSharp parses them.

What shall I do?

Comment: If you're stuck with HTMLWorker for some reason then I don't think there's any way to use it to achieve your goal. Instead I'd recommend changing the HTML that you give it using [something else](http://stackoverflow.com/q/56107/231316)

Comment: @ChrisHaas I was thinking using HtmlAgilityPack...